# Refuah Conditions

Tags: infertility

If someone asks you to provide names for Refuah, could you include someone who is experiencing infertility?

What prayers should you say so that G-d blesses someone with a child? Thank you & Shabbat Shalom.

Comment: See https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/699206/jewish/Is-there-a-prayer-for-infertility.htm